# ayuda con codigo plsql

Tags: plsql

Buen dia Solicito de su apoyo para revisar mi codigo ya que no soy muy buena para la programacion para pl sql lo que requiero es que actualice los registros de una tabla temporal a la tabla destino y vaya leyendo registro por registro, si el registro existe en la tabla destino que lo actualice si no existe que lo inserte

```
declare
    lv_ciudadsian             CIUDAD_ADM_SINC.CIUDAD_SIANTEL%TYPE;
    pei_nombre_ciudad         CIUDAD_ADM_SINC.NOMBRE%TYPE;
    pei_status_cuidad         CIUDAD_ADM_SINC.ESTATUS%TYPE;
    valorBusqueda             CIUDAD_ADM_SINC.CIUDAD_SIANTEL %TYPE;
    lv_usugsm                 VARCHAR2(20):= '&1';
    lrowExist NUMBER;

    CURSOR cr_CatCiudad IS
        SELECT b.nombre, b.ciudad_siantel, b.estatus 
        FROM CIUDAD_ADM_SINC B;
BEGIN
    OPEN cr_CatCiudad;
    LOOP
        FETCH cr_CatCiudad INTO lv_ciudadsian, pei_nombre_ciudad, pei_status_cuidad;
            EXIT WHEN cr_CatCiudad%NOTFOUND;
             dbms_output.put_line(':: VALOR lv_ciudadsian :: ' || lv_ciudadsian);
            IF lv_ciudadsian IS NOT NULL THEN
                valorBusqueda := lv_ciudadsian;
                SELECT CASE
                    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CIUDAD_ADM WHERE CIUDAD_SIANTEL = valorBusqueda)
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END INTO lrowExist from dual;
             DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('lrowExist '|| lrowExist);

                IF lrowExist = 1 THEN
                  UPDATE ciudad_adm a
                  SET a.nombre = (select b.nombre 
                              from ciudad_adm_sinc b
                              where a.ciudad_siantel = b.ciudad_siantel),
                      a.updated_when = SYSDATE,
                      a.estatus = (select b.estatus 
                              from ciudad_adm_sinc b
                              where a.ciudad_siantel = b.ciudad_siantel);
                    dbms_output.put_line(':: SE ACTUALIZARA EL REGISTRO :: ' || valorBusqueda);
                ELSE
                    dbms_output.put_line(':: SE INSERTARA EL REGISTRO NUEVO :: ' || valorBusqueda);
                    INSERT INTO CIUDAD_ADM 
                    VALUES ( (SELECT MAX(ciudad_id)+1 FROM CIUDAD_ADM), '0', '0', '4', '0', SYSDATE, pei_nombre_ciudad, lv_usugsm, '16', lv_ciudadsian, pei_status_cuidad);
                END IF;

            ELSE
                dbms_output.put_line('v_Tokens ESTA VACIO..!!!');
            END IF;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cr_CatCiudad;
END;
```

Comment: Buenas tardes ¿Podrias comentarme que version de Base de Datos estas usando? Por lo que veo podría ser realizado facilmente con un MERGE. Decime que Base tenés y veo de ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: ¿Cuál versión de Oracle está usando? mirar la vista **v$version** - 
¿El error es de compilación o de ejecución? -
¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: Esto es una tarea? lo pregunto porque hace 2 días hicieron la misma pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-Al **UPDATE** le hace falta la cláusula **WHERE**, y por ello está actualizando TODA la tabla.
2-Si la columna **CIUDAD_SIANTEL** es la llave primaria o es un índice unitario de la tabla **CIUDAD_ADM** entonces puede usar un bloque Declare/Begin/Exception para insertar y al atrapar  la excepción **DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX** proceder a actualizar.
3-Dado que con el cursor **cr_CatCiudad** ya tiene los valores de la columna **NOMBRE** y la columna **ESTATUS** no se requiere volver a consultarlos en la tabla, para insertarlos en la tabla destino.

Comment: muchas gracias ya quedo mi codigo

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias a todos asi quedo mi codigo

```
    lv_ciudadsian             CIUDAD_ADM_SINC.CIUDAD_SIANTEL       %TYPE;
    pei_nombre_ciudad         CIUDAD_ADM_SINC.NOMBRE               %TYPE;
    pei_status_cuidad         CIUDAD_ADM_SINC.ESTATUS              %TYPE;
    valorBusqueda             CIUDAD_ADM_SINC.CIUDAD_SIANTEL       %TYPE;
    lv_usugsm                 VARCHAR2(20):= 'ssss';
    lrowExist NUMBER;
    l_infoLogError_v          PKG_TIPODATO.MAX_VARCHAR2_ST;
    resultado                 PKG_RESULTADO.RESULTADO_RT;

    CURSOR cr_CatCiudad IS
        SELECT ciudad_siantel, nombre, estatus
      INTO lv_ciudadsian, pei_nombre_ciudad, pei_status_cuidad
      FROM ciudad_adm_sinc;
BEGIN
    OPEN cr_CatCiudad;
    LOOP
      BEGIN
        FETCH cr_CatCiudad INTO lv_ciudadsian, pei_nombre_ciudad, pei_status_cuidad;
            EXIT WHEN cr_CatCiudad%NOTFOUND;
             dbms_output.put_line(':: VALOR lv_ciudadsian :: ' || lv_ciudadsian);
            IF lv_ciudadsian IS NOT NULL THEN
                valorBusqueda := lv_ciudadsian;
                SELECT CASE
                    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CIUDAD_ADM WHERE CIUDAD_SIANTEL = valorBusqueda)
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END INTO lrowExist from dual;
             DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('lrowExist '|| lrowExist);

                IF lrowExist = 1 THEN
                  UPDATE ciudad_adm a                  
                  SET a.nombre = pei_nombre_ciudad,
                      a.updated_when = SYSDATE,
                      a.estatus = pei_status_cuidad
                   WHERE a.ciudad_siantel = valorBusqueda;

                    dbms_output.put_line(':: SE ACTUALIZARA EL REGISTRO :: ' || valorBusqueda);
                    dbms_output.put_line(':: VALOR pei_nombre_ciudad :: ' || pei_nombre_ciudad);
                    dbms_output.put_line(':: VALOR pei_status_cuidad :: ' || pei_status_cuidad);
                ELSE
                    dbms_output.put_line(':: SE INSERTARA EL REGISTRO NUEVO :: ' || valorBusqueda);
                    INSERT INTO CIUDAD_ADM 
                    VALUES ( (SELECT MAX(ciudad_id)+1 FROM CIUDAD_ADM), '0', '0', F_GETREGION(), '0', SYSDATE, pei_nombre_ciudad, lv_usugsm, '16', lv_ciudadsian, pei_status_cuidad);
                END IF;

            ELSE
                dbms_output.put_line('Catalogo ESTA VACIO..!!!');
            END IF;
            COMMIT;


    EXCEPTION

      WHEN  OTHERS THEN
                    resultado        := Pkg_Resultado.getResultado(DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack,
                                                       DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace);
            l_infoLogError_v := NULL;
            l_infoLogError_v := 'ActualizaCatalogo: Error encontrado: ' || pei_nombre_ciudad || ' ' ||
                                 DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack || ' : ' ||
                                 DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace;

      --    Se inserta en LOGS_ADM.
            Pkg_Log.p_inserta(pe_user_id           => lv_usugsm,
                              pe_clave_del_proceso => 'ACTCIUD',
                              pe_parametros        => substr(l_infoLogError_v,
                                                             1,
                                                             4000),
                              pe_direccion_ip      => 'SERVER',
                              pe_id_mensaje        => 0);
           COMMIT;
           END;
  END LOOP;
    CLOSE cr_CatCiudad;
END;
/
```

Comment: Considera por favor explicar tu respuesta, pues el solo responder con código se considera de baja calidad, te recomiendo leer [answer]